# javascript as keyword, multiple names after "as" in import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, module

I noticed this import in a javascript file

`import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom"`

from my past experience I could see the `as` keyword being used to create alias for imported module.

So does this simply import `Router, Route, Switch` modules? or does it use those words as aliases for `BrowserRouter`? how is the `as` keyword being used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as` only applies to `BrowserRouter`. The other two (`Route` and `Switch`) are unaffected.

That import is identical to this:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
```

or this, for that matter: :-)

```
import {Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
```

It's importing three named exports from the module `"react-router-dom"`:

- `BrowserRouter` (using the local name `Router` to refer to it in the module's code)
- `Route` (using the same name for the local identifier)
- `Switch` (using the same name for the local identifier)

Comment: FWIW, I go into modules and `import` syntax and such in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 13 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.